# What does (1UL << 22) mean in MySQL Source Code Documentation

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-8.0

I am updating an existing library in Java I have to connect to MySQL 8 but the source code documentation has a #DEFINE I don't understand. I'm looking specifically at the client capability flags at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/group__group__cs__capabilities__flags.html.

Some of the capability flags show the decimal value so I can convert them to unix for easier bitmasking but there's some flags like `CLIENT_CAN_HANDLE_EXPIRED_PASSWORDS` which has the value of `(1UL << 22)`.
I have no idea what `(1UL << 22)` means to be able convert that to something I can use in java.

Comment: why java tag if you don't understand C document?

Comment: It should be 1 shifted left 22 times, that is 2^22, that is 4*1024*1024.

Comment: Because I'm working on Java and I've done plenty of stuff but never seen that (They don't have java documentation)

Comment: Surely you should read the docs for the language it's written in (C++)? UL is unsigned long, for example.

Comment: In this specific case it is just a flag which value is, in a specific register, the bit 22 of the register (bits count starts with 0)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thanks for the help, that's done what I was expecting. Didn't realise it was as simple as a bitshift, it was the UL that was throwing me :)

Comment: I expected UL might have stood for Unsigned Long I've done C/C++ but I'd never seen a #define like that so hadn't realised it was as simple as a bitwise operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `(1UL << 22)` means 1 shifted left 22 times within an Unsigned Long.

That is 2^22, that is 4*1024*1024.

In your case `CLIENT_CAN_HANDLE_EXPIRED_PASSWORDS` is just a flag that is enable, in its specific unsigned long register, if  bit 22 of the register is 1 (bits count starts with 0).